# Interrupt JQuery setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have two buttons which supposed to display two different series of graphs. Each series of graphs getting displayed gradually one under the other with 3 seconds delay. If user clicks first button he gradually gets shown first series, if user clicks second button the first series gets deleted and the second series starts to show gradually one by one.

Here is the piece of code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="show_graphs(1)"></button>
<button type="button" onclick="show_graphs(2)"></button>

<div id="stats"></div>

function show_graphs(type) {
    var i = 0;
    $('#stats').html('');
    $.getJSON('stats.php?type=' + type, function (data) {
        for (chartData in data) {
            i++;
            var timer = setTimeout(function(index,d1){
                return function() {
                    var chart = new AmStockChart();
                    dataSet.dataProvider = data[d1];
                    // etc. etc.

                    $('#stats').append('div id="chartdiv' + index + '"></div>');
                    chart.write("chartdiv" + index);
                }
            }(i,chartData), 3000*i);
        }
    });
```

The problem is if user clicks second button before first series completed appending then the div gets cleared but first series continues to append its graps and then second series get appended. So as I udnderstand I need to stop first setTimeOut before running it second time with another parameters. I understand I need to use

```
clearTimeout(timer)
```

... but I can't figure out where to use it. Wherever I put it I get 'unknown variable timer'.

Comment: the problem is the variable `timer` is local to the `$.getJSON` callback function...

Comment: where are you using the `clearTimeout(timer)`?

Comment: Would it help to declare it outside and then use inside the fucntion?

Comment: yes it would... the variable has to be declared in a shared scope

Comment: I thought it could be <button type="button" onclick="clearTimout(timer);show_graphs(1)"></button> or <script> clearTimeout(timer); show_graphs(1);</script> but those wouldn't work

Comment: in that case try `window.timer = setTimeout(....)`

Comment: How would it look like?

Answer (score 2):

Note that `clearTimeout()` to have any effect must be called *before* the timeout duration, i.e. before the bound function is invoked. Secondly, in your case, since the graph rendering would already have started, `clearTimeout()` alone will not be sufficient.

You can use some kind of flag to indicate whether a graph rendering operation should be aborted or not.

For ex:

```
// cancel indicator
var cancelGraph = {}, timer;

function show_graphs(type) {

    // abort any other rendering
    clearTimeout(timer); // clear timeout if rendering not already started

    // cancel other running operations
    for(var otherType in cancelGraph) {
        if(otherType !== type) cancelGraph[otherType] = true;
    }

    $('#stats').html('');

    // set current one as non-cancelled
    cancelGraph[type] = false; 

    var i = 0;

    $.getJSON('stats.php?type=' + type, function (data) {
        for (chartData in data) {

            if(cancelGraph[type] === true) break; // abort: don't continue rendering

            i++;
            timer = setTimeout(function(index,d1){
                ...
            }(i,chartData), 3000*i);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Great! What if 'type' can be different in amount, i.e. it actually gets fetched from Mysql DB for unique types and display buttons with those types, for example those could be from 3 to 11 types?

Comment: In that case, you can run a small loop to ensure all others are cancelled. See the updated.

Comment: Seems very good but there is something going wrong there. I have made jsfiddle with local date source so it could be seen that it breaks down somewhere: http://jsfiddle.net/fbKSa/18/

Comment: Basically it starts a new cycle without stoppint the previous one for some reason. the jsfiddle above could show that.